# Caste of Sujātā

Tags: the-buddha

What was the caste of Sujātā, the woman who offered the Buddha a bowl of rice milk? I am trying to check a reference to her as a Brahman. She is described as a milkmaid, daughter of a landowner.

Comment: There're quite a few Sujata's and they're mentioned [here](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/s/sujaataa.htm)

Answer (score 3):

She is called "mother of Yasa" in [VN Mahāvagga](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/english/metta.lk/04i001-e.php#topic7), and her name "Sujātā" is declared in AN Ekakanipāta [Etadagga Pāli](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=20&item=152&items=1&eng=metta_e).

Buddha took her food before he enlightened Nibbāna. After Buddha taught VN Anattalakkhaṇasutta to Pañcavaggī, Buddha taught [Anupubbīkathā](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/29469/10100) to Yasa and parents.

This is her profile in [AN Ekakanipāta Atthakathā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/read_rm.php?B=14&A=8419&h=suj%C4%81t%C4%81#hl). It shows Sujātā wasn't born in rich Brahmaṇa caste family. **She was born in rich Vessa caste family** because she was born in [Kuṭumbhika-kula](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/read_rm.php?B=14&A=8419&h=suj%C4%81t%C4%81vatthu,seniyaku%E1%B9%ADumbika#hl).

Brahmaṇa-kula = <personal-name>+[maṇava](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=13&A=1037&h=M%C4%81%E1%B9%87avak%C4%81ti#hl) (Brahmaṇa caste family)

Brahmaṇa-mahāsāla-kula = rich Brahmaṇa caste family

Gahapaṭi-mahāsāla = <personal-name>+kuṭumbiya (rich Vessa caste family)

**Example** from Aṅ.A. (manoratha.1) Etadaggavagga Paṭhamavagga [etadaggapadavaṇṇanā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/read_rm.php?B=14&A=2634&h=moggall%C4%81nattheravatthu,s%C4%81riputto%20br%C4%81hma%E1%B9%87amah%C4%81s%C4%81lakule,saradam%C4%81%E1%B9%87avo,Mah%C4%81moggall%C4%81no%20gahapatimah%C4%81s%C4%81lakule,siriva%E1%B8%8D%E1%B8%8Dhaku%E1%B9%ADumbiko#hl):

> ito satasahassakappādhike asaṅkhyeyyakappamatthake **sāriputto** **brāhmaṇamahāsālakule** nibbatti, nāmena sarada**māṇavo** nāma ahosi. **Mahāmoggallāno** **gahapatimahāsālakule** nibbatti, nāmena sirivaḍḍha**kuṭumbiko** nāma ahosi.

Comment: I suppose the mother of Yasa and Sujātā who offered ascetic Gotama Siddhārta a bowl of rice milk are two ladies. It's evident that, at the time of offering Sujātā (who offered ascetic Gotama Siddhārta a bowl of rice milk) was just had a son after her marriage to a man of equal caste. Please refer, https://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/lifebuddha/15lbud.htm

Comment: She fulfills her vow every year ([anusaṃvaccharaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/read_rm.php?B=14&A=8419&h=suj%C4%81t%C4%81vatthu,anusa%E1%B9%83vacchara%E1%B9%83#hl)) after she had a son, so there is only one Sujātā. However, it is possible that her family is Brahmaṇa caste because her family is the leader of the village, which normally Brahmaṇa.

Comment: Thanks @Bonn sir! Actually I didn't know that. Everyone, sorry for my mistake and please ignore my comment above. Bonn sir, It's said that Sujātā was a baroness. So her cast might be Vaishya? (May be, I'm not sure.) Vaishya people engaged in banking and lending money. For example, "Komati caste".

Comment: @Damith You are right. She was born in Vessa caste. I already edited. Thank you.