# What are the established rules set for a person to Become a Buddha other than, that, he should have lived as a King?

Tags: the-buddha, enlightenment

Long time ago , I was reading some text related to Buddha online and saw that there were many pre-conditions already set for a person to become a complete Buddha. I remember very clearly , the first condition was that the person should have lived as King in the past. While googling again to see the other conditions, I am unable to find the original article. Is anyone aware of such conditions ? Can someone help . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Theravada perspective: [this paper claims](https://digitalcommons.wku.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1011&context=phil_rel_fac_pub) (page 7) that the origin of the idea of a relationship between being a ruler in a previous life and becoming a Bodhisatta is from the Vessantara Jātaka, was expanded on and embraced by Mauryan rulers, and eventually more-or-less canonicalized due to the influence of various South and South East Asian rulers (see also the Mahāvaṃsa and Jinakālamālī). I don't have a full English Buddhavaṃsa available to check, but the Madhuratthavilāsinī (the commentary) doesn't mention that all of the preceding Buddhas were kings/rulers. However the Theravada does not emphasize broad Buddhahood for everyone, and the primary factors for the next Buddha are a prediction and the complete decline of the current Buddha's teachings.

Mahayana perspective: according to the Lotus Sutra, everyone is predicted to become a bodhisattva, and therefore a Buddha (or already is, depending on the interpretation), and no Sutra that I know of insists on a specific past-birth path that includes kingship.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, it's not about becoming a king, but it's about cultivating the perfections ([parami or paramita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81ramit%C4%81)) that makes one qualified to become a Sammasambuddha.

Kingship is not likely to be the criteria to become a Buddha. Rather, becoming a king could be a byproduct of cultivating perfections.

There are 10 perfections from the Theravada tradition, from the link above:

> 1. *Dāna pāramī*: generosity, giving of oneself
> 2. *Sīla pāramī*: virtue, morality, proper conduct
> 3. *Nekkhamma pāramī*: renunciation
> 4. *Paññā pāramī*: wisdom, discernment
> 5. *Viriya pāramī*: energy, diligence, vigour, effort
> 6. *Khanti pāramī*: patience, tolerance, forbearance, acceptance, endurance
> 7. *Sacca pāramī*: truthfulness, honesty
> 8. *Adhiṭṭhāna pāramī*: determination, resolution
> 9. *Mettā pāramī*: goodwill, friendliness, loving-kindness
> 10. *Upekkhā pāramī*: equanimity, serenity

Ven. Bodhi stated in the introduction to [A Treatise on the Paramis from the Commentary to the Cariyapitaka](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/wheel409.html):

> It should be noted that in established Theravaada tradition the
> paaramiis are not regarded as a discipline peculiar to candidates for
> Buddhahood alone but as practices which must be fulfilled by all
> aspirants to enlightenment and deliverance, whether as Buddhas,
> paccekabuddhas, or disciples. What distinguishes the supreme
> bodhisattva from aspirants in the other two vehicles is the degree to
> which the paaramiis must be cultivated and the length of time they
> must be pursued. But the qualities themselves are universal requisites
> for deliverance, which all must fulfill to at least a minimal degree
> to merit the fruits of the liberating path.

[This answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/23133/471) has a hint in the suttas with regards to the degree to which the perfections must be cultivated on the path to Buddhahood.

> To a person unblemished,
> constantly searching for purity,
> a hair-tip's worth of evil
> seems as large
> as a cloud.
> [SN 9.14](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn09/sn09.014.than.html)

Answer (score 1):

It could be the [Buddhavaṃsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhava%E1%B9%83sa) -- there's a partial a copy of it here:

- [Chronicle of Twenty-four Buddhas](http://www.myanmarnet.net/nibbana/gotama/gcobv12.htm)

The chapters I see -- i.e. 1, 22, 23, 24 -- all have the same format: starting with "Royal household life", then "Renunciation", and "Attainment of Buddhahood".